# How to easily include .ly files in a .tex document?

Tags: lilypond

## The context

I am generating an hymn booklet (containing mostly text), and I want to easily insert snippets of music scores based on `.ly` files I already have.

I have two kind of files:

- my `.tex` files, that should be compilable without lilypond code in it
- my `.ly` files, that I also use to generate `.midi` files and regular music sheets.

(Purpose is to be able to modify them independently - and to tidy up my `main.tex`.)

## My question

I am looking for an easy way to include my already existing `.ly` files in my `.tex` document with such kind of pattern:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
    [...]
\begin{document}

    Some regular text

    \begin{lilypond}
        \input{part/mylyfile.ly}
    \end{lilypond}
\end{document}
```

## My trials

I have seen the principle of the [two steps compilation](http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.12/Documentation/user/lilypond-program/Invoking-lilypond_002dbook#Invoking-lilypond_002dbook) with first `lilypond-book`, then `(xe)latex` ; an interesting [for-newbee lilypond-in-latex-MWE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203381/lilypond-latex-integration) ; and to finish, the [automation of the compiling with arara](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111055/how-to-run-latex-and-lilypond-book-in-one-command)...

I am able to run the MWE and generate related `.pdf` document.

## My issues

However, I'm stuck with following issues:

- I have noticed that `\input` doesn't work with the `lilypond`-environment. Is there a way to call an external `.ly` file?
- If I plain copy-paste my `ly`-file into the environment, I get plenty of errors, such as

  ```
   livret.lytex:40:44: Erreur : syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting SCM_FUNCTION or SCM_IDENTIFIER or SCM_TOKEN
    \override Lyrics.LyricText .font-shape = #'italic
  ```

  that refers to

  ```
  emph = {
    \override Lyrics.LyricText.font-shape = #'italic
  }
  ```

  - I also get errors for my `\tuplet` that I have to replace with `\times`.

Would you have any ideas of which idea I could explore in order not to be forced to re-write all my `.ly` code ?

Comment: did you see this page http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.12/Documentation/user/lilypond-program/An-example-of-a-musicological-document#An-example-of-a-musicological-document

Comment: `\lilypondfile[options]{myFile.ly}` seems indeed to be what I'm looking for! (I'm going to test it, thx for the link !)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentionned by [touhami](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280287/how-to-easily-include-ly-files-in-a-tex-document#comment675317_280287), the solution is to use the `\lilypondfile[options]{myFile.ly}` command. Available options are detailed in the [lilypond online documentation](http://www.lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/usage/music-fragment-options).

Below is the workflow to compile your document:

## The document

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
    [...]
\begin{document}

    Some regular text.

    \lilypondfile[noindent,quote]{myFile.ly}

\end{document}
```

**Important:** You have to save this file as `filename.lytex` and not as a `.tex` file.

The `myFile.ly` is a normal lylipond-file.

## Compiling

(I give here my ready-to-go compiling work-flow. Of course, you need to adapt it to your needs.)

#### Working directory

In your working directory, you need:

- Your `filename.lytex` file (see over),
- The `myFile.ly` file you're calling in your `.lytex` file
- A folder called `LilyPondPrecompile`

#### Commands

Via your terminal, go to your working directory. Then :

1. **Pre-compiling with `lilypond-book` (i.e. from `.lytex` to `.tex`)**

   ```
   $ lilypond-book --pdf --format=latex --output=LilyPondPrecompile filename.lytex
   ```

   (Note that if you call your `.ly` file or other `.tex` files that are located in your `workingDirectory/part` sub-folder, you have to pass this argument into previous command line: `--include=part`)
2. **Move into your `LilyPondPrecompile` subfolder**

   Previous step generated a `.tex` file out of the `.lytex` one. To keep folders clean, we decided to put the result (i.e. produced files) of this pre-compiling into a sub-folder (that what `--output=LilyPondPrecompile` stands for). We now have to change our working directory to compile the `.tex` file.

   ```
   $ cd LilyPondPrecompile/
   ```
3. **Compile the `.tex` file (i.e. from `.tex` to `.pdf`)**

   ```
   $ pdflatex filename.tex
   ```

   Repeate this step if needed. (Note that calling `pdflatex LilyPondPrecompile/filename.tex` from your original working directory seems not to work).

Your done!