# Compiling with lilypond-book

Tags: compiling, lilypond

The `lilypond` environment requires that you compile with lilypond-book, which in my case is found in the directory `D:\Program Files (x86)\LilyPond\usr\bin\lilypond-book.py`. I've added this directory to my PATH environment variable, but typing `lilypond-book document.tex` in the command line gives the result
"'lilypond-book' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file." All the compiling programs found in `D:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin` are .exe's, whereas lilypond-book is a .py, which I suspect has something to do with it but I don't really know enough to be sure. How do I go about compiling with lilypond-book?

Comment: Perhaps this might help:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/246320/69378

Answer (score 2):

Lilypond book is a [Python](https://www.python.org/) script. You will need Python installed, and then you can run `lilypond-book.py` (with the file extension), or add `.py` to Windows' list of executable file extensions if you really want to skip adding the extension.